# BackupManager - any "bmgr wipe" alternative?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

The `bmgr wipe` command doesn't work. Also disabling the `BackupManager` didn't help removing the backup sets. Is there any alternative way to remove those sets?
Is there any option for that in the Google account settings on the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the website
[google dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard)

After you log in with your backup account, you can see your backups under the "Android" section.

At the end of this section, you have an option to erase backup data

Comment: Negative. I don't see my backups under the "Android" section. But when I run the bmgr list sets command, I see two backup sets.

Comment: Are you sure you set up your backup account?
Under Settings, there is a Backup & reset option and under this section you must set your backup account.

Comment: Yes, completely sure.

Comment: I am not sure but your backup seems to not arrived the server. You can force to do it immediately by this two commands.
`bmgr backup <your package in your manifest file>` and then
 `bmgr run`

Comment: Too odd, I had to power on my device and connect it to wifi to see those backups with my PC. Thanks anyway.